Wrong path deploying on Heroku
I'm looking for some help.
I need to deploy a Symfony 7 app on Heroku but i'm facing a problem
My app run with docker, my docker-compose.yml :
version: '3.8'

services:
  database:
    container_name: database
    image: mysql:8.0
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: soigneMoi
      MYSQL_USER: symfony
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    ports:
      - 4306:3306
    volumes:
      - .mysql:/var/lib/mysql
  php:
    container_name: php
    build:
      context: ./php
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 8443:443
    volumes:
      - ./apache/default.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
      - ./apache/default-ssl.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-ssl.conf
      - ./etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
      - ./app:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - database
  phpma:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_USER: root
      PMA_PASSWORD: secret
      UPLOAD_LIMIT: 20M
    ports:
      - 8899:80

My Procfile : web: heroku-php-apache2 app/public/
This is the structure of my app
structure
I tried to deploy on Heroku with the Github method, all is fine but i'm having a blank page
The logs :
error
The path is wrong but I don't understand why. This should not be app/app but just app/
I can fix the require_once path by replacing require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php'; by require_once dirname(__DIR__, 2).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';
but it is still looking in app/app/public/index.php
If anyone could help, that would be great.
Thanks.
